# Does dd require CAP_SYS_RAWIO?

Tags: linux, permissions, dd

A little while ago, I found out from [this](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-7.html) that there used to be a way to semi-permanently disable the ability of even root to modify immutable & append-only flags (`lcap CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE`) or perform raw read/write operations (`lcap CAP_SYS_RAWIO`). I wanted to try this, but since the system-wide capability bounding set has since been removed, I patched the Linux kernel in such a way that commands requiring either capability are always denied. As such, I assumed that this would render `dd` useless as a way of bypassing and disabling these restrictions since `lcap CAP_SYS_RAWIO` "disallows root to write to the raw disk or raw memory".

To see if my modifications were successful, I ran `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=mbr.img bs=512 count=1`. The operation was successful, so I assumed that this was allowed because it was only a read operation. So, I ran `sudo dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1`, but, to my dismay, this was successful, too. I checked if I had missed any code testing for `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` in the Linux kernel, found that I had, modified it as necessary, rebuilt it, reinstalled it, and tried it again. Once more, `sudo dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1` was successful.

I'm curious to know now if `dd` doesn't require `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` or if it doesn't count as "raw I/O", just in case I didn't miss anything else.

Answer (score 1):

`man 7 capabilities` lists the things that `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` controls, and reading and writing block device files is not one of them.  `dd` does its work using the normal `read` and `write` system calls; it has fancy features for choosing the size of the input and output buffers and transforming the data while copying it, but it it doesn't really do anything special for the I/O itself.

Comment: In the webpage I gave, `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/kmem seek=1740644 bs=1 count=1` is implied to be raw memory access.

Comment: That's because `/dev/kmem` represents raw memory, and you need `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` to open that specific file.  The use of `dd` is irrelevant; *any* program trying to write (or read) `/dev/kmem` needs `CAP_SYS_RAWIO`.